# How can I predict values from new inputs of a linear model in R?

Tags: r, forecasting, linear-model

I've created a linear model in R: `mod = lm(train_y ~ train_x)`.  I want to pass it a list of X's and get its predicted/estimateed/forecasted Y.  I looked at `predict()`, but I think that is for something else, or I just don't know how to use it.

I'm guessing by taking the coefficients of my model, I could manually plugin the test_x variables one-by-one, and get a predicted Y, but I'm guessing there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want the predicted values for `train_x` = 1, 2, and 3, use `predict(mod, data.frame(train_x = c(1, 2, 3)))`.

Comment: I was leaving out the "train_x =", and adding that solved my issue! thank you kindly